# How to fix Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded without increasing the execution time?

Tags: php

I developed this script which browses through my folders online and checks the php files on the folder and compares them with the list php files on local in order to identify whether my website may have been hacked and the hacker may have deposited a php file on my server. If there is a new file that I have not personally entered in the database while i was on local 127.0.0.1, the script will send me a mail asking me to check the file. My problem is that i keep getting 
**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded** . How to solve it without increasing the execution time ?

Here is my script

```
<?php require('mettre_avant_haut.php');

?>  <h3 align='center'>This Code scans your Hosting for malicious Php files. If potential viruses are found, there will be displayed below this message</h3> 

<?php $host_actuel = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$url_dossier_actuel = url_dossier_actuel($mettre_https='Oui');

function afficher_php($dir='.')    {    global $host_actuel;      global $url_dossier_actuel;
        require('configurations.php');  



          if (is_dir($dir)) {       $objects = scandir($dir);       foreach ($objects as $object) {
          if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {          if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir")            {
               afficher_php($dir."/".$object);              }           else            {
                //unlink   ($dir."/".$object);

                $fichier_actuel = "$dir/$object";

                $ficher_a_inserer = str_ireplace('./','', $fichier_actuel);


                if(preg_match("/.php/i", $ficher_a_inserer))
                {


                //Si on est sur le dossier local, on verifie
                // Pour voir si le ficher php est deja dans la base de donne
                $verification = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `nom_fichier` FROM `ojm_all_php_files` WHERE `nom_fichier`='$ficher_a_inserer' LIMIT 1 ") or die(trigger_error("Error on file $ficher_a_inserer").mysqli_error($connection));

                    $compter = mysqli_num_rows($verification);

                    mysqli_free_result($verification);
                        /*  Si le compte donne 0 est que on est sur le local alors on enregistrre le fichier    Autrement on m'envoit un mail pour expliquer que ce ficher est suspect  */
                    if($compter==0)
                    {           #########################################################
             $id_ojm_peoples = @$_SESSION['id_ojm_peoples'];

$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?: getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?: getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?: getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

$date_created = date('Y-m-d');


//Si le id_ojm_peoples est superieur a 0 alors on verifie a base de ca autrement on verifie a base de ip            if($id_ojm_peoples>0)           {
                $champs_a_utiliser = 'id_ojm_peoples';
                $valeur_champs_a_utiliser = $id_ojm_peoples;

            }           else            {
                $champs_a_utiliser = 'ip';
                $valeur_champs_a_utiliser = $ip;

            }
                    ###########################################
                        //On enregistre le fichier car on est en local
                        //sI ON est en local
                        if(preg_match('/127.0.0.1/i', $host_actuel))
                        {
                            $insertion = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `ojm_all_php_files`         VALUES(NULL, '$ficher_a_inserer', '$valeur_champs_a_utiliser', '$date_created')         ") or die(mysqli_trigger_error("Error while inserting the local file in the database").mysqli_error($connection));

                            echo "<br>$ficher_a_inserer has been added as a new local file";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Si on nest pas en local
                            //Ca signifie qu'on est en ligne et que ce fichier nest pas
                            //dans la base de donnee donc un nouveau fichier

                             //Alors on envoit un mail

################################################################## //On envoit un mail a ladmin

////////////////////////////////////////////   //On envoit un mail de dmande de verification de compte $nom_expediteur = "iUseFaith Robot";         $email_expediteur = 'no-reply@mywebsite.com';       $email_destinataire = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 

            $sujet = "Suspect $url_dossier_actuel / $ficher_a_inserer";         $message_html = "    On your website $url_dossier_actuel,  the file <strong> $ficher_a_inserer </strong> seems either not to have been on your local server or you did not update the table named <strong>ojm_all_php_files</strong> with the name of the new file.<br><br>       If that file is not a hacked file, kindly update the table <strong>ojm_all_php_files</strong> localy by going to the website localy and accessing the file <strong>afficher_php.php</strong>. <br>

Afterward, kindly copy the new table <strong>ojm_all_php_files</strong> to your hosting.

";      //echo "$message_html";
            //On envoit un mail a l'email du site $envoyer_mail = envoyer_mail($nom_expediteur,$email_expediteur,$email_destinataire,$sujet,$message_html,$message_texte='',$pj='');
##################################################################



  alert_warning(" <b>  <br> $ficher_a_inserer is a php file that was not on your original local webserver but is now on the online webserver. kindly cross check whether you have allowed that file <br> </b> ", $type='danger');





                        }
                        ################################################


                    }





                }
                ############################################
                            }

          }         }       reset($objects);
              }



        }  ############################################################


afficher_php($dir='.');




?>
```

Comment: You need to optimize your queries also.

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `set_time_limit(0);` as the very first command in your script ?